# How do I get rid of a directory that I created, but apparently don't have permission to?

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions

I created a directory when I uncompressed an .xlsx file.  I think I then tried to delete it from within Chrome (I think it was a upload file dialogue).  I got a message that I couldn't, so I didn't think much of it as I was doing other things.

Now that I'm looking at this closer, it seems that the permissions are screwed up somehow.  Here are the properties:

[image: folder properties]

It now says that it can't display the current owner:

[image: Advanced Security Settings]

If I click on Change, I get this:

[image]

Not sure how this could have happened.  Any ideas how to rectify it?

Comment: I would just use `takeown /f file` and `cacls file /G username:F` from within a command prompt.  You must be an Administrator in order to do this.  If you are on a domain, depending the ACL of the file, it might have to be a domain Administrator.  Since you can't provide the ACL I can't say one way or another.

Comment: @Ramhound, good to know about that command, but got an `ERROR: Access is denied`  Yes, I'm running the command prompt as an Admin.

Comment: Show us the ACL on the directory that contains the file.  You have tried to simply restart, right?

Comment: @Ramhound, how do I show the ACL?  Simply restart what?  My computer? No.  Why would I need to restart my computer to delete a file?

Comment: you can try using `psexec` to gain localsystem privileges, if you want. download psexec from technet and run it like `psexec -s \\localhost cmd`.  then try to grant everyone full control to the file. from there you should be able to take ownership of the file as your normal user. If you cannot, then than is an indication that the actual error is not permissions based, but somting seriously wrong with the filesystem (or disk) or the API. in that case try `chkdsk` and `sfc,exe` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx

Comment: @Adrian - If you don't want to restart the computer.  Just restart Windows Explorer process.  I can't help without knowing more about the current ownership of the file, or at least the folder, that contains the folder.

Comment: @Ramhound, you have as much info as I do.  If you know of how to get more info from the object, please let me know. :)

Comment: @FrankThomas - Since we are dealing with a file, from within an archive file, that isn't meant to be decompressed normally.  It could be as simple as the file doesn't actually exist on the disk, and windows explorer, is being windows explorer :-)

Comment: @Adrian - *How* you get the information is up to you.  I can't teach everything.

Comment: From experience, I know that restarting will work. As for *why* this is happening, and if there is an alternative, I don't know. It may just be because Windows Explorer.

Comment: @FrankThomas, this is an extracted file set.  There's nothing magical about these files.  They are just standard files.  All of the files were deleted except for the worksheets directory and possibly whatever is inside of it.

Comment: "why would I need to restart my computer to delete a file?"  My guess is a process has it locked and isn't releasing it because it crapped out, keeping the file in a locked state that can't be modified.  As others have suggested, try rebooting (as it's the easiest fix to try), and if it's still there after the reboot, try deleting it again.

Comment: @Ramhound, a reboot did solve the problem.  Post it and I'll give you the credit.  Though I'm still not sure why it was locked.  The file/directory didn't show up in Process Explorer.

Comment: @Adrian - Even if I was the one to suggest a reboot, I am not going to submit an answer suggesting you reboot, because I feel that is something that should have already been tried before the question was asked.  Operating Systems do weird things sometimes, its a fact of life, rebooting solves most of those weird things ( or provides more insight like being unable to boot because of a system file corruption ).